# 2½ hour layover Doha (same airline) - do I need to go through customs/immigration? Recheck bags? Enough time?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, layovers, filipino-citizens, short-connections, doha

I have some queries and kind of worried about my international flight for Sweden. My flight would be from my country of origin Manila, Philippines to Sweden but having a 1 stop layover at Doha.

My ticket belongs to one airline but from Manila to the Doha I have a different flight number and I am bothered about the possibility of missing my connecting flight thinking that I only have 2 and half hours layover and if I need to fall inline with immigration and custom I know it will take time and if I still need to check out and in again my luggage.

Comment: What's the airline? Are the two flights on a single booking?

Comment: What's the airline? Are the two flights on a single booking?

Comment: What time of day ad what day of the week do you arrive/depart Doha?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the ticket is bought from Manila to Sweden, the two legs will have different flight numbers. That is normal. Also, in this case, you will not go through immigration or customs, you will just come out of your first leg plane with hand luggage, and will board the second leg.

Again, with above assumption, you will get both boarding passes at Origin, and also will check your luggage in at same time. You will get luggage back only at Sweden. In an unlikely event of airline missing your luggage in transit at Doha, they are supposed to deliver it to you in Sweden at the next available flight.

2.5 hours is almost enough time for a direct transfer like this. I have done 1 hour transfers at this airport without any rush or running. As Airline sold you the whole itinerary, if you miss second leg because first one arrives late, tgey will put you on alternative flight at their expenses.

Comment: Perhaps you meant "almost certainly enough time"?